# Problem with Kotlin Duration in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new with Android Studio and Kotlin and I have some trouble with Kotlin Duration. When I try to do following in my code:

```
val test: Duration = Duration.parse(value = timeClose)
```

I get this error message:

> This declaration needs opt-in. Its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime' or '@OptIn(kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime::class)'

I use Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1 with Kotlin 212-1.7.10

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what the error is telling you to do: mark it with one of the suggestions.

```
@kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime
val test: Duration = Duration.parse(value = timeClose)
```

or

```
@OptIn(kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime::class)
val test: Duration = Duration.parse(value = timeClose)
```

The reason you have to do this is that the Duration class is in the `ExperimentalTime` package, which means that this is an experimental preview, as the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-experimental-time/) states:

> Note that this API is in a preview state and has a very high chance of being changed in the future. Do not use it if you develop a library since your library will become binary incompatible with the future versions of the standard library.

Comment: Which leads to the question what time library can a developer use that does not require @OptIn?

Comment: Since the duration is now available in the kotlin time package, just use that one: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/